# FATAL ERROR IN TWO-TASK SERVER: error = 12571

Tags: oracle, oracle-9i

oracle9i/windows2003,java application.

oracle crash, alert log file contains sdh_ora_4636.trc which contains:

```
*** 2012-05-05 13:53:32.000
*** SESSION ID:(100.50539) 2012-05-05 13:53:32.000
FATAL ERROR IN TWO-TASK SERVER: error = 12571
*** 2012-05-05 13:53:32.000
ksedmp: internal or fatal error
Current SQL statement for this session:
SELECT 
   ID, CATEGORY, RESTOID, RESTAROID, CREATETIME, SNMPORT, UPDATETIME, 
   ALIAS,SERIALID, ISOFFLINE, VERSION, SNMPREAD, DESCRIPTION, NAME, SNMPWRITE, 
   MAXALARMSEVERITY, PHYSICALADDRESS, DN, IDENTIFIER, IPADDRESS, VENDORID, CITYID, 
   REGIONID, MEMODELID, MEMODELNAME, SECTOR, PRESTATUS, STATUS, BASESTATION, HOTPOINTID, ACID 
FROM MANAGEDELEMENT WHERE (NAME = :1)
```

I checked the SQL; it runs quickly.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening? Would upgrading my database solve the problem?

Comment: Oracle 9i is no longer supported. Why do you use such an outdated version?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you mean if i upgrade my database to oracle 10, it will not have the problem?

Comment: I mean you will have a hard time getting help for a version that is no longer supported - especially for "internal errors". Btw: 10.1 is also de-supported I think. You should really think about upgrading to 11.2 (especially as 12c is on the doorstep)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  this database is installed many years ago.It is easy to upgrade it,but if the errors remains?

Comment: Anyway, this is a network problem. From Metalink: "The most common cause for the above error is an ungraceful disconnection of a session from the oracle db while the db is currently running a dml statement issued by that session. The error is recorded when oracle attempts to reply back to the session with the results of the dml and cannot access the session. Overall database operations are usually not affected. ".

Comment: @Phil i found the explain in the web,i do not understand why it is a network problem.it means my application sever temporarily disconnect from my database server?

Comment: Yes. A network glitch or firewall disconnecting the session for some reason.

Comment: @Phil  will it cause the database crash？

Comment: Did you have to restart the instance?

Comment: @Phil yes.we have to restart the instance!